# creating a photo album gallery

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a photo gallery where the user can upload images, but I'm  trying to make it where the users can create photo albums to store their images in.

The process works like this.

1. The User starts by creating an album (the album is stored in the album table like this)

[image]

2. Then the user uploads images into the album. (the images are stored
   in the gallery table like this)

[image]

What I'm trying to accomplish is getting the images to load based on the album they're in. Like this.

[image]

So on "Test Album 1" I only want the photos in that album to load and the same with "Test Album 2".

I created an **album.php** page that I want the images to load on based on what album they are in.
For the two links that are shown in the image, I call them like this. Based off of the albums table.

`<a href="../gallery/album.php?=<?php echo escape ($ga->album_id);?>">`

Now here is where I'm lacking experience / knowledge. I need to join the two tables together and I can't figure out how to write this query correctly.

I want to query the albums table, album_id and Join it with the gallery table.

Here is the query I have as of now and need help with.

```
  $gallery = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT
albums.album_id,
gallery.id,
gallery.added,
gallery.album,
gallery.title,
gallery.description,
gallery.file_name
FROM
albums
LEFT JOIN gallery ON albums.album_id = gallery.id WHERE gallery.album = albums.album_id ORDER BY gallery.id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");
```

Then I call my images like this.

```
foreach($gallery->results() as $g){
    ?>
    <li>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="<?php echo escape($g->album); ?>"
    href="../images/gallery/<?php echo escape($g->file_name); ?>">
    <img src="../images/gallery/<?php echo escape($g->file_name); ?>" class="max-img-border"></a>
    <div class="galleryh"><?php echo escape($g->title); ?></div>
    <div class="galleryp"><?php echo escape($g->description); ?></div>
</li>

    <?php
}
?>
```

If I can just figure out how to write that JOIN query correctly I will be good to go.
Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `album_id` to the gallery table.

This field would be a foreign key linked to the albums table.

This will allow you to query the table without JOIN while giving you data integrity.

This assume you want one album per image.

Comment: I want the user to create an album first then they can add as many images to that album as they want.

Comment: so first insert the album, and make the album required before user upload and read the album_id value in order to insert

Comment: How I have it setup now is the admin/moderator is required to create an album first. Then it directs them to the image upload page and there is a select menu to choose which album they want to dump their images into. This is all done in a private section for certain members of the website. The normal users will then go to the public gallery page and can see all images uploaded like shown in my image above. I just need to archive each album as well. So the public users can see images from a specific event if they would like. I think I get it now. Just need to research the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Some ecommendations:

You need to decide

- whether all images are stored in only one album.
- Each image has at least one album assigned
- images can be "orphan" - no album assigned currently
- albums may be empty

Set up a RDS scheme like

```
  album ---(1:n)---> image (where n = 0 - infinite)
```

or

```
  album <---(n:n) ---> image
```

or

```
  image ----(n:0) ----> album (!!)
```

Next:

- your join matches `... WHERE gallery.album = albums.album_id ...`

`gallery.album` contains the album title (varchar) and `album.album_id` an id (auto index?). That won't work and isn't best practice: the link between album and gallery image must be by an album id, otherwise it will be hard to rename an album later on.

I haven't checked further as these are basics to be sorted out first.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ID numbers to reference across tables. 
But this Album title should work ok. It is just if you allow users to change the name of the album later you have to update all gallery rows and not just the Album title for that album.id

Try

```
SELECT
albums.album_title,
gallery.id,
gallery.added,
gallery.album,
gallery.title,
gallery.description,
gallery.file_name
FROM
albums
LEFT JOIN gallery ON albums.album_title = gallery.title ORDER BY gallery.id DESC LIMIT (you want here)
```

This will go through all Albums and then output the corresponding images in gallery id order from high to low.

Comment: So would you recommend adding album_id in the gallery table between id and album. I tried you solution but couldn't get it to work correctly. I'm going to keep trying though.